# How do I copy png/mp4 files from another directory to a folder of my choice?

Tags: python, tkinter, shutil

I want to get the address of a file with filedialog.askopenfilenames() of tkinter lib and copy that file to the file I want.

As explained above, I got the address using filedialog.askopenfilenames() and using that address, I use shutil lib to

```
list_file = []
     files = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir="/", \
                                         title="Please Choose the File", \
                                         defaultextension='.mp4', \
                                         filetypes=(("*.mp4", "*mp4"), ("*.gif", "*gif"))))
     if files == '':
         messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Please Choose the File")
     for i in list_file:
         shutil.copy(list_file[i], "image_file")
```

I wrote the code, but there was no error and no copy was made.

Answer (score 1):

the problem with your code is that you are checking "list_file" which is empty, what you should try is this instead:

```
for i in files:
    shutil.copy(i, "image_file")
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8STd.png

although, if you try to copy to the same folder it will crash, what you could do is:

```
for i in files:
    try:
        shutil.copy(i, "image_file")
    except shutil.SameFileError:
        #idk do something like change 
        #the name or something
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9FAR.png

thats with your existing code, there is a couple more problem like the name file doesn't change so it would only create one copy, and if you only choose one file it would treat it as a str, not a tuple, so you would have to create a check for those.

Comment: Try using "print("random_str")" to see if the program is even going inside the loop

Comment: I wrote it `def function_for_mp4():
    list_file = []
    files = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir="/", \
                                        title="Please Choose the File", \
                                        defaultextension='.mp4', \
                                        filetypes=(("*.mp4", "*mp4"), ("*.gif", "*gif")))
    for i in files:
        print("a")
        shutil.copy(i, r"image_file")

    if files == '':
        messagebox.showwarning("Caution", "Please Choose the File")`
I opened Pycharm with Permission,but not copied,
a printed succesfully

Comment: it works perfect for me in VSCode, maybe you aren't looking in the right spot? because aside of that i can't think of a reason why it wouldn't work, try placing a complete path instead of just the name of the file, (fun fact i forgot to put the name of the file on the path and it created a file with the same name)